# How to store x amount of uint8s inside a byte32?

Tags: solidity, assembly

I'm trying to store an array of `uint8` but its not very gas efficient. This is my current solution of storing things:

`uint8[5] public VALUES = [10, 11, 12, 13, 14];`

The problem is that I will have about 40 of these `VALUE` arrays, and if I test that in Remix, I can't even start the Contract (I've waited minutes for the initialisation and it doesn't occur, so I am assuming this is very inefficient).

My next planned solution is to store the values in a string:

`string public VALUES = "1011121314";`

And then I would retrieve numbers by getting their index `i` and `i+1`, and using `parseInt(string)` to get the number. But I'm not so sure about the efficiency of doing that.

So since I've heard about assembly being very efficienct within Solidity, I'm wondering if there was a way to store multiple `uint8` values in a larger data format, such as a `byte32`? My current use case is 5 `uint8` values, so perhaps `byte5` would only be required? Also how would I retrieve such values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Organize the 5 `uint8` values in a single struct. When you compile the contract, make sure optimization is turned on. Since storage slots are 32 bytes, the compiler will automatically squidge your `uint8`s together in storage for maximum gas efficiency.

Comment: This approach works. In my test of initialising 5 of those arrays, (total of 30 x uint8), it costed me ~1.28 million gas. Using a struct costed only ~260k gas, giving me a reduction of about 80%.